# Sending credentials in a POST request via Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

How do I send credentials using Fiddler in a POST request (or any Http Method)? I don't see anything in the Composer tab.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That entirely depends on what sort of credentials your server uses. If it's using HTTP authentication, the headers go in an **Authorization** header. If your server uses cookies, the creds go in the **Cookie** request header. If your server uses HTTPS client certificates, the credential is attached to the TLS connection itself and does not appear anywhere in the HTTP request.

If you are simply trying to authenticate to a service that uses HTTP authentication with your current Windows credentials, tick the **Automatically Authenticate** box on the Composer's **Options** subtab.